# Green's theorem area formula

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, greens-theorem

I am assigned to calculate the area beneath the curve $y=x^2$ and above the $x$-axis using the formula

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_C x\,dy\,-y\,dx$$

from $0\le x\le2$

while this seems simple to me I parameterize $x=t,y=t^2$ so $dx=dt$ and $dy=2t\,dt$. Plugging this into the equation I get
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2t\,(2t)\,dt\,-t^2\,dt$$ which gets you $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\,t^2\,dt=\frac{4}{3}$
however, integrating regularly you get $A=\int_0^2 x^2\,dx$ which is $\frac{8}{3}$. Could anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: You’ve only integrated along part of the curve. There are two straight segments that you have to do as well.

Comment: you have worked out one of 3 paths pieces of the boarder of the region.  you still have the line x = 2 and y = 0.

Comment: It is easier to use the identity $$\int_C (Pdx + Qdy) = \iint_A   ( Q_x-P_y) dA\,.$$ In your case the line  integral $$I = \int_0^2\int_0^{x^2}dydx. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression,

$$A=\oint_C (x\,dy-y\,dx)$$

$C$ represents a closed curve, oriented counter-clockwise, that bounds the region over which the area is calculated.

In the problem of interest, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C x\,dy-y\,dx&=\int_0^2 (-0)\,dx+\int_0^4 (2)\,dy+\int_{-2}^0(2t^2-t^2)\,dt\\\\
&=4-\frac43\\\\
&=\frac83
\end{align}$$

Comment: Is there any reason as to why for the first integral there is a negative sign in front of the zero, and on the last integral the limits are from -2 to 0 instead of from 2 to 0? Also, how do we determine the orientation of x=2 and the x axis?

Comment: The orientation of $C$ is counter-clockwise.   On the first integral $dy=0$ and $y=0$.  Thus, we have $x\,dy-y\,dx=0-(0)\,dx$.  On the last integral, the limits go from $-2$ to $0$ since we are traversing the contour counter-clockwise.  And similarly, for the second integral, we have $x=2$, $dx=0$ and thus $x\,dy-y\,dx=2\,dy-(0)$ and again the orientation takes us from $y=0$ to $y=2$.  -Mark